# How to turn a txt file to csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a txt file that has 214 columns(with the data separated by spaces) and about half a million rows.

I want to convert txt to csv, and have used this code:

```
import csv

txt_file = r"myfile.txt"
csv_file = r"myfile.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"), delimiter = " ", quotechar=" ")
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w', newline='\n'),delimiter=' ', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

But this exports my data into a csv file where all the columns are just separated by spaces, in the 1st `A` column in excel... I'd ultimately like to be able to convert txt to csv and in the process remove the `10th-48th, 50-61, 65, 67, 68, 71-75, 77, 78, 80-88, 91, 93, 96-100, 102, 105-110, 112-114, 116-119, 122-126, 128-134, 136-140, 142-151, 153-155, 160-162, 165-169, 172-173, 175-177, 179-187, 189-196, 198, 199 & 201-214` columns. I am sure this is simple but am pulling my hair out trying to work out how to do it

Comment: Why do you have the delimiter as `' '` in the `csv.writer`?

Comment: Because I thought delimiter was asking what was separating my data... and it's a space... so I put a space :-D

Comment: Ahh ... Nope, for a `csv.writer`, that's what delimiter will be used in the output.  It gets the fields based on what you pass to `writerow` or `writerows` (which for a vanilla writer is simply a list or list of list for `writerows`)

Comment: The `delimiter`of `reader` must match your current format, while the `delimiter` of `writer` should be your desired format. `writer` never works with the original `csv`, that's the point of having a separate `reader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change

```
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w', newline='\n'),delimiter=' ', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

to

```
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w', newline='\n'),delimiter=';', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

since you want your writer to use ';' as a delimiter in the generated csv file.
For removing the columns, i see no other way than iterating over them in a for-loop and only writing the current column if it isn't one of these.

Eg.:

```
first_row = next(in_read);    
for x in range(0, length(first_row)):
    if x not 10:
       write()
```

Comment: I think you're looking for something like `enumerate` in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the delimiter of the `writer` to a comma.

```
import csv

txt_file = r"myfile.txt"
csv_file = r"myfile.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "r"), delimiter = " ", quotechar=" ")
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w', newline='\n'),delimiter=',', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                                                   # changed this ^

out_csv.writerows(in_txt)
```

As for removing columns, you can just throw them away for each line. A generator expression allows you to modify each line without loading them all at once

```
cleaned_column_iter = (line[0:10] + line [49:50] + line [62:65] for line in txt)
                                # add more elements as desired ^
out_csv.writerows(cleaned_column_iter)
```

Comment: Thanks MrMiyagi I think that worked! I can't open it because it's too big so it seems to have worked, at least I should be able to delete out some columns now - cheers :)

Comment: @JacintaTonkin See the added note on how to remove columns.